# Why does github create a fork in commit tree when squash&merge

Tags: git, github

I had the following history in my fork:

```
x feature & origin/feature
|
x upstream/feature
```

Then I made a pull-request which was successfully squashed & merged. When I pull changes from the upstream, my history looks like this:

```
x upstream/feature
|   x feature & origin/feature
| /
x
```

I was expecting the following:

```
x feature & origin/feature & upstream/feature
|
x
```

So is the expected behavior of github pull requests or I have messed something up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub's "squash and merge" button *always* creates a new commit that consists of the result of applying every commit in the pull request.  (More precisely, it creates a new commit that uses the *merge action*—"merge as verb"—but makes an ordinary, non-merge commit.  This is also what the command-line `git merge --squash` does.)

When there is *exactly one* commit in the pull request, this makes a copy of the one commit.

If there are two commits you get:

```
* (upstream/feature) the squash commit that is not a merge
| * (feature, origin/feature) commit 2
| * commit 1
|/
* the common base across your GitHub repo and their GitHub repo
```

Note that if the upstream repo uses true merge, the graph is almost the same, except that it reads:

```
* (upstream/feature) the merge commit that IS a merge
|\
| * (feature, origin/feature) commit 2
| * commit 1
|/
* the common base across your GitHub repo and their GitHub repo
```

Either way, if you intend to use the merge-or-"merge" (i.e., not merge but squash) commit, you should move your own branch to point to their commit and forget all about your series of commits.  If the upstream people did a squash merge, this can be difficult: you must get *your* entire team to discard their version of `feature` and switch to the tip commit on the upstream's `feature`, *even though this means losing your own commits*.  If the upstream folks did merge your commit, it's much easier: you can simply allow Git to perform a not-actually-a-merge-at-all fast-forward "merge" from the tip of your `feature` to the upstream `feature`.

Comment: thanks, torek, that's seems to be really the case. I guess I can just reset my branch to `upstream/feature` now, but I'm wondering is it the conventional way to sync with upstream after squash&merge pull request? I guess this is what you're suggesting here _you should move your own branch to point to their commit and forget all about your series of commits_

Comment: _If the upstream folks did merge your commit, it's much easier: you can simply allow Git to perform a not-actually-a-merge-at-all fast-forward "merge" from the tip of your feature to the upstream feature._ - yeah, that's what I expected, a fast-forward merge locally. I guess if I simply `git pull` after squash&merge I'll get a **redundant** merge commit with no conflicts on my local `feature` branch. Is it the conventional way to go with github's squash&merge pull request workflow?

Comment: Right, if you do a fetch-and-merge (aka `git pull`) you will get your own redundant merge sitting atop their squash-merge and your own commit(s). But unless you *are* the upstream as well as the person making the pull request (the "downstream"? :-) ), you have no control over what the upstream folks do. At my current $job we're effectively "both sides" of this equation (we are using a paid GitHub account for private repos) and we make different merge choices based on coordination with ourselves: sometimes squash, sometimes merge, sometimes the request-er has to rebuild the commit series.

Comment: Incidentally, before this point (of doing all these variations at $work) I had kind of expected the GitHub clicky button to be smarter, and to do fast-forward not-really-merge-after-all operations more often.

Comment: _you have no control over what the upstream folks do_ - yeah, but I have control over how I update local history, either through `git pull` resulting in a redundant commit or `git reset` that will keep the linear history but will lose commits in my work. I'm wondering what you do for squashed merges? I have control over both sides - we use paid GitHub account as well.

Comment: _and to do fast-forward not-really-merge-after-all operations more often_ - [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-merges/) states that simple merge is performed using `--no-ff`. How do you get that option in the clicky `merge` button? :)

Comment: I either delete or reset my local branches after they're squash-merged. I don't think they (GitHub) offer any way to do `--ff-only` merges, but "rebase and merge" (which is really rebase + `git merge --ff-only`) might leave existing commits in place when rebasing. I have not actually tested this yet though.

Comment: got it, thanks a lot for your input. _we make different merge choices based on coordination with ourselves: sometimes squash, sometimes merge, sometimes the request-er has to rebuild the commit series_ - I'd love to hear the logic when making a decision. Any chance you want to share them in a separate question I will create? :)

Comment: Well, we're still experimenting with what works best for us, so it's kind of hard to make a recommendation! :-)

Comment: it's interesting that if you always use `squash & merge` option on github your history will still always be linear regardless of your local merge commits because as we identified with `squash & merge` there are no true merges hence there are no commits with two parents that could reference your local merge commit